# Conditional traversal of a tree structure, adding extra parameter to action

Tags: c#, lambda, tree, action

I have a tree structure that has a Traverse function, the traverse function takes an action that it will perform on each layer:

```
public void Traverse(Action<ILayer> action)
        {
            action(this);
            foreach (var child in children)
                child.Traverse(action);
        }
```

However I find myself about to write code like this:

```
    private List<ILayer> filteredList = new List<ILayer>();
    private string condition;
    void AddLayerIf(ILayer layer)
    {
        if (layer.Type == "condition")
            filteredList.Add(layer);
    }

    void main()
    {
        filteredList.Clear();
        condition = "Image";
        rootLayer.Traverse(AddLayerIf);
        List<ILayer> allImageLayers = filteredList;
    }
```

And that feels totally wrong. Could I send the two variables as parameters instead of having them global? or is there an even better trick I am missing? I started to write the action as a lambda but not sure that is right either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some lambda which feels much better! Any advice on improving welcome :)

```
ILayer imageLayers= new ImageFolder("Images");

rootLayer.Traverse(
    (ILayer x) =>
    {
        if (x.Type == "Image")
            imageLayers.AddChild(x);
    });
```

Comment: You don't have to specify the type, so `x =>...` instead of `(ILayer x) ->...`, but otherwise this is how I would do it.